# Rasterised CAGradientLayer vs CGGradient efficiency wise

Tags: macos, uikit, core-graphics

Creating a CAGradientLayer is adding a new sublayer to a view's existing layers (with `shouldRasterize` as `true`). Whereas CGGradient is drawing over the view within the `draw` method.

Is there a major speed advantage of using one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a note within a [Ray Wenderlich article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/410-core-graphics-tutorial-part-2-gradients-and-contexts) on Core Graphics that mentions how the two differ. It turns out there is a big difference between how the two are rendered, this is the note:

> Drawing static views with Core Graphics is generally quick enough, but
>   if your views move around or need frequent redrawing, you should use
>   Core Animation layers. Core Animation is optimized so that the GPU,
>   not the CPU, handles most of the processing. In contrast, the CPU
>   processes view drawing performed by Core Graphics in draw(_:).

As this is a general note this applies to `CALayer`s vs `draw(_:)` as well.